# Nested For Next Loops: Outer loop not iterating

Tags: excel, for-loop, nested-loops, vba

I have a range of data from `A2:A34` with various names in it that I need to copy to the range `E9:E14`. I only need to copy and paste unique names (I don't need a double of the same name). I am pretty sure using a nested `For Next` loop is the way to go but I'm having trouble getting the outer loop to go to the next iteration. Right now this is only giving me the last name in the in range `A2:A34` repeated in `E9:14`. I was looking into using `Exit For` but when I added that in the code, the outer loop iterated but then the inner loop started over at 2.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Below is my code:

```
Sub FillTable()
  Dim tableCount As Integer
  Dim rowCount As Integer

  For tableCount = 9 To 13
    If Range("E" & tableCount).Value = "" Then
      For rowCount = 2 To 34  
        If Range("E" & tableCount).Value = Range("A" & rowCount).Value Then

        ElseIf Range("E" & tableCount).Value <> Range("A" & rowCount).Value Then
          Range("E" & tableCount).Value = Range("A" & rowCount).Value
        End If
      Next rowCount
    End If
  Next tableCount
End Sub
```

Comment: It appears your data will always be in very specific format since you know the exact number of unique values to iterate thru.  If so, why not just copy the list to column E and then use the built in 'Remove Duplicates' from the Data menu?

Comment: It's quite difficult to visualise what you'r etrying to do without some sample data. The easiest thing to do it step though (debug) and work out why it isn't doing what you expect. For example perhaps an `IF` is not evaluating as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've been stepping through and the problem is that once the ELSEIF statement is true and it copies the first name, it iterates but the outer loop doesn't. So once this happens the first if statement under For rowCount becomes true and it pastes the 2nd unique name in the same spot on the table.

Comment: How would a portion of code look like if you just wanted to search through range A2:34 for unique values and just paste them into Column B right next to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if VBA is really needed for this exact issue but hopefully the below code will help. I switched the loops so that you only iterate through the large list of names once and then you iterate through the second list checking for duplicates. I also added a variable so it would allow for more than 5 unique names (unlike when tablecount was 9 to 13).

Fair warning - this is a quick and easy solution. It is neither elegant nor optimized.

```
Sub FillTable()

Dim tableCount As Integer
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim n As Integer

n = 0
For rowCount = 2 To 34

  For tableCount = 9 To 9 + n
      If Range("E" & tableCount).Value = Range("A" & rowCount).Value Then
        ' name already found, break out of loop
        Exit For
      ElseIf Range("E" & tableCount).Value = "" Then
        Range("E" & tableCount).Value = Range("A" & rowCount).Value
        n = n + 1
      End If
  Next tableCount

Next rowCount

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great for what I needed. Thanks a lot. The n variable counter was what I was missing.

Comment: One thing I'm a bit confused about is the `For tableCount = 9 to 9 + n`. How come if you leave the `n = n + 1` out of the code it won't iterate to the next rowCount and instead gets stuck in the tableCount loop?

Comment: I just chose 9 as the value because you said you wanted the range to start at cell E9. Typically you would set n=1 and then the For loop would be from 1 to n. If you take out n=n+1, n will always = 0, and tableCount will always = 9. The inner For loop will run once and only once because the exit condition (tableCount = 9 + 0) has been reached. The outer For loop with rowCount will still iterate but you can't tell because there is nothing coded. You can test it by throwing in a "MsgBox(rowCount)" between Next tableCount and Next rowCount.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your description of your goal does not match the code.

You are copying from (to simplify a bit) col A to col E.
Does col E already contain data? If not, why the first "if" stmt to see if some cell is empty?
If yes, E already contains data, then you want to loop through E to see if E already contains the new name.
I'll also point out that E has room (per your spec) for 6 names, while the source has 33 names.

Without knowing your goal, I won't suggest real code, but, perhaps a way of approaching the problem:
Create functions that do only very simple little things. For example, perhaps simplest, a function to see if name already in list. Note that I assume a value for highest used row, be sure to define it, whether as 14, or as some counter.

```
Function Is_Name_Already_Present_in_E( Name-to-check as String ) As Bool
   Is_Name_Already_Present_in_E = False               ; Default we'll return if don't find name.
   for r = 9 to highest-so-far-used
      if Name-to-check = Range( "E" & r ).value then  ; If found name in list,
         Is_Name_Already_Present_in_E = true          ; then return true.
         exit function
      end if
   next r
end function                                          ; If scan whole list, and not found,false.
```

I'm sure there are a few syntax errors, but they should be easy to resolve.

Then, create a simple function to add your new name to E. Perhaps something like (Beware the assumptions!):

```
Function Add_New_Name_To_List( Name  as string ) as bool
   if highest_used_so_far >= 14 then
      Error "No room to insert name:" & Name & ". Rejected."
      Add_New_Name_To_List = false
      exit function
   end if
   highest_used_so_far = highest_used_so_far + 1
   range( A & h_u_s_r ).value = Name
   Add_New_Name_To_List = true
exit function
```

Then, your main becomes a very simple (fake code example because I don't know your intent):

```
for r = 2 to 34
    if not Is_Name_Already_Present_in_E( range( "A" & r ).value ) then
        if not Add_Name_to_E( range( "A" & r ).value ) then
           ... what to do if add fails. ...
        end if
    end if
next name
```

Break your problem into pieces and it should be clear how to write each piece. Good luck.